# Pushing key/value pairs to an array, loses key out of forloop

Tags: php, arrays

I get my data from the database, but want to add 2 keys to them. So I add them in a for loop. If I dump (simple function that prints the array with pre tags) the single result in the for loop, it's correct, when I dump the 2dimensional array outside of it, it doesn't have the keys anymore..

For some reason it doesn't push it to the 2dimensional array?

$results is a 2dimensional array btw.

```
    //add amount and subtotal to the array's elements
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $result['amount'] = $sessionShoppingCart[$result['artikelnummer']][1];
        $result['subtotal'] = $result['amount'] * $result['Verkoopprijs'];
        $this->dump($result);
    }

    $this->dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change an array within the `foreach` you can do two things.

Reference the array value with `&`:

```
foreach ($results as &$result) {
```

Or use the key and modify the array:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    $results[$key]['amount'] = $sessionShoppingCart[$result['artikelnummer']][1];
    $results[$key]['subtotal'] = $result['amount'] * $result['Verkoopprijs'];
}
```

Comment: Oh god, I feel stupid. Didn't know you had to reference the array in php tho..Figured it was the same as in C# Thanks!